# How can I pass the current SurfaceView into other object methods?

Tags: java, android, oop, parameters

I'm trying to make my first android game, just a pong clone really, I have a "PongView" class that extends SurfaceView and is my only view. It has objects of my "Ball" and "Paddle" classes. I just started moving code related to things, like detecting wall collisions, to the Ball and Paddle classes to tidy up my main view a bit and realised that i'd need to give these classes a way to know the views width and height. At the moment my work around is just to intialise a global variable inside the surfaceviews *surfaceChanged* method that stores the width and height of the view, like so:

```
//at the top of my class
private int viewWidth;
private int viewHeight;
..

@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

        //INITIALISE viewWidth and viewHeight here
        //so that they can be passed as parameters
        viewWidth = getWidth();
        viewHeight = getHeight();

        //some other irrelevant code here
    }
```

Then I pass them as parameters:

```
ball.handleWallCollision(viewWidth, viewHeight);
```

However i'm not sure this is the way to go about it, as i will need to pass them in quite often i imagine. I thought it would be better if i had a copy of the current PongView in each class? But i'm not sure if thats true or how/when to go about getting it.

What would you recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use object of surface view class that was used to setting view in activity.That object is live and will contain all changes regarding that surface view

```
SurfaceView sur=new SurfaceView(this);  /// you created object
setContentView(sur);
//you do your work
//surface view is running
```

Now you want to exit from that activity.Then in onDestroy() used
CommonClass.ObjectVraible=sur;

this line will save current state of the surfaceview

Comment: Thanks for response and the information! Well i know the object you mean but could you show me what code i would put in my Ball or Paddle classes where i need to access this object? i'm not sure how i would go about this sorry.

Comment: There is a concept  serialization in which we save our object.If you revert back it then all class member restore their state to original state where we save object.It used in storing game state.So similarly now you just have to use that class object

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and the new information but i'm not sure we're understanding each other? i have a "PongActivity.java" file with the same code in it as you posted above. But once i enter my view (PongView.java) i start using objects of other classes i've made, for example "Ball.java" which holds information about my ball sprite. It's in Ball.java that i would like to get / need the width and height of the PongView i was previously in. I'm not sure how to do this. What code would i write in "Ball.java"? Sorry if i'm not clear/ misunderstanding and thanks for your time

Comment: No need for sorry.Today i am little less busy.But i didnot got ur issue.So btter luck and hope you solved it